# How do I exclude files using .htaccess conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've implemented a .htaccess file on my website that consists of a rewrite rule for all requests. I would like to add a condition so that when a certain file is requested the rewrite rule is not applied. How can I do this and in a way that would allow me to add more in the future if need be. I will paste my code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What's the point? The rules you wrote already explicitly ignore existing files through the `!-f` condition. What you want is already in place I'd think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond lines tell mod_rewrite when to apply the RewriteRule.

As @Niels commented - the "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" line tells the system to not execute your RewriteRule if the request is for an existing file.

If you wanted the rule to execute generally, even if the file exists, and only not rewrite for a specific file, you'd remove that line, and add a more specific RewriteCond line.  Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ="Foo.html"
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html for details.

Comment: I apologize. I had the .htaccess written for me at the time and wasn't entirely sure how it was working exactly. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can we prefix file path like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /-"files/"f`?